# Trying to generate a random number for a loop but it doesn't seem to be working. Why is this?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a loop but I need a random number to actually get it to work.

```
var j=0;
while(j < patrons.length){
  var books = patrons[j].booksOut;
  var fine = patrons[j].fine;
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1)) + 1; //the random number
  for(var i=randomnumber;i<books.length;i++){ //me trying to replace i with the random number
    if(books[i].isOverdue()){
      fine = fine + 5.00;
    }
  }
  patrons[j].fine = fine;
  j++;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to replace the i in my for loop with the random number it doesn't seem to work properly. Anyone know why?

My complete code:

```
var Author = function(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
};

var Book = function(title, Available, publicationDate, checkoutDate, callNumber, Authors) {
  this.title = title;
  this.Available = Available;
  this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
  this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
  this.callNumber = callNumber;
  this.Authors = Authors;
};

Book.prototype.checkOut = function(){
  this.Available = false;
  var temp = new Date(1000000000);
  var d = new Date()-temp;
  var res = new Date(d);
  this.checkoutDate = res;
};

Book.prototype.isOverdue = function(){
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var singleDay=1000*60*60*24;
  var todayDate = new Date().getTime();
  var difference = todayDate - this.checkoutDate.getTime();
  if(Math.round(difference/singleDay) >= 14){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

var Patron = function(firstName, lastName, libraryCardNumber, booksOut, fine) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.libraryCardNumber = libraryCardNumber;
  this.booksOut = booksOut;
  this.fine = fine;
};

Patron.prototype.read = function(book){
  this.booksOut.add(book);
}

Patron.prototype.read = function(book){
  this.booksOut.remove(this.booksOut.length);
}

//creating author objects
var authors = []
authors[0] = new Author("Edgar","A. Poe");
authors[1] = new Author("George","Orwell");

var mybooks = []
mybooks[0] = new Book('Animal Farm',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 10,authors);
mybooks[1] = new Book('1984',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 11,authors);
mybooks[2] = new Book('A Tale of Two Cities',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 12,authors);
mybooks[3] = new Book('The Raven',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 13,authors);
mybooks[4] = new Book('Forgotten Lore',true,new Date(2000,5,20), new Date(), 14,authors);

var patrons = []
patrons[0] = new Patron('Patrick','fill1',1,mybooks,0.00);
patrons[1] = new Patron('Lira','fill2',1,mybooks,0.00);
patrons[2] = new Patron('May','fill3',1,mybooks,0.00);
patrons[3] = new Patron('Kyle','fill3',1,mybooks,0.00);
patrons[4] = new Patron('Bob','fill4',1,mybooks,0.00);

var j=0;
while(j < patrons.length){
  var books = patrons[j].booksOut;
  var fine = patrons[j].fine;
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1)) + 1;
  for(var i=randomnumber;i<books.length;i++){
    if(books[i].isOverdue()){
      fine = fine + 5.00;
    }
  }
  patrons[j].fine = fine;
  j++;
}

for(i=0; i < patrons.length;i++){
  console.log(patrons[i].firstName+" has taken the following books:");
  for(j=0;j<patrons[i].booksOut.length;j++){
    console.log(patrons[i].booksOut[j].title);
  }
  console.log(patrons[i].firstName+" has fine = "+patrons[i].fine);
}
```

Comment: The random number doesn't take the number of books into account. What happens if the generated number is greater than or equal to `books.length`?

Comment: well, the random number will be from 1 to 17 (why that range?) ... how many items in the books array?

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? Try logging the randomnumber that you're generating and checking that it isn't bigger than `books.length`

Comment: @DanielBernsons - there's probably no error - if `randomnumber >= books.length`, then the for loop just never runs

Comment: @JaromandaX agreed, that's the most logical, but it could also be an error in the isOverdue function.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the loop(s) in full context. I manually tried setting i to 20 and the result output is always "[user] has fine = 0".

Answer (score 0):

Without sample values for patrons, the best I can offer is to use `books.length` as your max value. Why are you even picking them at random? Is there a broader problem you are trying to solve?

```
const isOverdue = () => true;
const patrons = [
  { booksOut: [{ isOverdue }], fine: 1.0 },
  { booksOut: [{ isOverdue }], fine: 2.0 },
  { booksOut: [{ isOverdue }], fine: 3.0 },
];
let j = 0;
while(j < patrons.length) {
  const books = patrons[j].booksOut;
  let fine = patrons[j].fine;
  const randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * books.length);

  for(let i = randomnumber; i < books.length; i++) {
    if(books[i].isOverdue()) {
      fine += 5.00;
    }
  }
  patrons[j].fine = fine;
  j += 1;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(patrons, null, 2));
```

Edit per comment:

```
Book.prototype.isOverdue = function() {
  return [true, false][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]
}
```

Something like the above will make `isOverdue()` answer randomly yes or no.

Comment: Perhaps this is a classic XY problem. I'm trying to generate a random number so that it triggers the overdue function and uses that to make it so the user has a fine.

Comment: Might want to put the random number in `Book.prototype.isOverDue()` so that it randomly decides when something is overdue.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample you have provided, you are using `new Date()` to set the checkout date for each book, which is setting it to the time of execution.

Therefore, when you are calling `isOverdue()` it is always checking whether today minus now is >= 14 days, which it never will be, so `isOverdue()` will always return false.